# On Objective-C: which is the root directory in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios

Which is the root directory in iphone and where does all the files documents will be stored? Why we are using only the NSDocument directory to copy a file in that place and then we are reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, iOS doesn't allow a program to access arbitrary files in the system. A program can only access files within its sandbox, see [this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW44).

A program needs to get the path to its sandbox using a public API, because the sandbox path is not known at the compile time. That's why you see what you see in the sample code.

Comment: k...thank u Yuji and i am an fresher if i want to be very good in objective c programming part which book i want to refer can u please guide me?

Comment: For Objective-C for a Mac app, the book by Aaron Hillegass is the undisputed best book. He now has an iPhone programming book too, which I haven't read myself. But judging from my experience with the other book, I can heartily recommend it: http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide